# Why is the closed unit interval compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Looking at the definition for compactness, i.e. "every open cover has a finite subcover", it seems like $[0,1]$ wouldn't be compact, since you can't construct a cover with a finite subcover that fills the bounded space.

This is obviously wrong because of Heine-Borel. Any counter-examples?

Comment: Can you give an example of an open cover you think has no finite subcover?

Comment: I *can* construct a cover of $[0,1]$ with a finite sub cover: $\{[0,3/4),(1/4,1]\}$. Not only does it have a finite subcover, it's actually finite itself.

Comment: Also, you copied the definition incorrectly, "every **open** cover has a finite subcover".

Comment: Your cover has no subcovers. Since neither of the two intervals covers the whole of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @user167289 These is not required for a cover, only that $[0, 1]$ is contained in the *union* of the covering sets.

Comment: You can do something similar for R however it is not compact